# Convert columns to separated list in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I have an excel file. This file contains a different list for each of the rows. And each list(whole row) have different values in the each columns. I want to convert the excel that I give below for example. Here I want to turn each of the lines into columns with titles on their side.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 4 columns by however many rows, put this in G2,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$4, IF(COLUMN(A:A)=1, 1, INT(ROW(10:10)/5)), MOD(ROW(1:1), 5)), TEXT(,))
```

Fill right and down.

[image]

For 7 columns by however many rows,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$G$4, IF(COLUMN(A:A)=1, 1, INT(ROW(16:16)/8)), MOD(ROW(1:1), 8)), TEXT(,))
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for using Excel functions to do this instead of resorting to VBScript.  Nice!

Comment: Thanks @CraigCocca - I'm bored and there just aren't many quality questions on a weekend.

Comment: _____________Sweet formula !

Comment: Beautiful Done Mate :)

Comment: "on a weekend" is redundant.

Comment: answer is perfectly working. But how? how can i modify this for another examples. when i have 7k row and 15 column how can i modify function. can you explain which numbers i must change when my data is changed?

Comment: I have provided a second example. You should be able to extrapolate any combination of columns and rows from the two examples.